# How to stop trigger if pipeline fails Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have pipeline need to run at every one hour.
Using tumbling window trigger.
If pipeline is successfull it should continue to run every one hour.
If pipeline fails with some reason, next instance, I mean pipline should not run for next hour.

How can we stop trigger if pipeline fails.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this feature is not available in the **Azure data factory**. You can raise a feature request from the Azure data factory feedback.

[image]

Alternatively, you can add a web activity in your pipeline upon the failure of the previous activity. In web activity, you can make a call to an HTTP request to Stop the trigger.

Refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggers/stop) to Stop a trigger.

Comment: How to generate the Authorization Bearer token here, any details steps.

Comment: You can refer to this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/160681/how-to-automatically-stop-trigger-in-azure-data-fa.html) for similar ask.